# How can i have JAAS authentication in JBoss call a java server class?

Tags: java, authentication, jboss

I have a very simple question for which I have not found an answer in SO or elsewhere (namely, the hundreds of pages of JBoss security documentation):

I want to implement a login function (specifically, database logging), at the point when authentication happens through JAAS, without the client having to make a separate REST call.

I'm not an expert, but my understanding is that the authentication happens through a database query off in the JBoss XML, without calling the server directly.  Since JBoss is doing this and connecting the authentication with the server war, I'm hoping that there is a hook available to have it kick off a REST call, or call the Java code through another mechanism.

Couldn't find a duplicate but please point me to it if it answers *this exact question*.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is with webapps and not with client apps so I do not fully understand your question, but it is clear you are suffering a serious missunderstanding.

`want to implement a login function (specifically, database logging), at the point when authentication happens through JAAS.`

To do that you just need to implement a LoginModule class and register it with JBoss.

Let's make this clear. JAAS is executed at the server, as part of a resouce security policy. When a resource needs authenticated access, the JBoss servlet executes the security policy related to it. The security policy includes

a) how the container (the JBoss server) requests the authentication data. But that part is not specified by JAAS. JAAS only specifies how the container passes that data back to the login module.

b) the login module that the container runs to check that the authentication data is correct, and to fill/provide the principal that will be passed to the application in the server. The login module makes its checks as it wants (let it be SQL query, or LDAP queries, or calling a WS, or...).

The `without the client having to make a separate REST call.` has no relationship with JAAS. It may be that the policy requires to setup a cookie for authentication. I am pretty sure (again, I am used to webapps) that if you use Basic HTTP authentication you do not need extra calls. Then again **JAAS is only related with checking the user/password and providing/filling the principal. How the data is obtained by the container (JBoss server) is not related to JAAS**.

`I'm not an expert, but my understanding is that the authentication happens through a database query off in the JBoss XML, without calling the server directly. Since JBoss is doing this and connecting the`

The "JBoss XML" does nothing, it is just a description of the security policies. When you deploy an app, its descriptor tells which resources are to be protected by which security policies. Do not confuse the terms. Which performs the SQL query (or LDAP query, or webservice call, etc..) is the container (the "JBoss server") through the login module.

From the rest of your question, I cannot understand what are you trying to do. Do you want the JAAS module to call your webapp code directly?

Comment: Haven't read the whole thing, but 2 clarifications:  1) this is a web app - by client I mean the browser; 2) Yes, there is SQL in the login-config.xml, in JBoss.  I *think* you're saying this happens through the server.  But nevertheless, I don't think it does "nothing."  Thanks.

Comment: The "standard" login module of jboss (the one provided with jboss) gets the SQL queries(one for user/password, other for roles) as parameters in JBoss config. But that is only *configuration data for the login module* (the login module is described in the same file, nearby).

Comment: Of course, if you use that login module, then when the login module gets executed it ends running these SQL queries. But you may replace that login module by another that instead of SQL queries uses an LDAP query.

Comment: OK - I think we're getting caught up in semantics:  my understanding of JAAS is the whole mechanism and login process; yours is more specific and, I'm guessing, accurate.

Thanks for your help, and the long and well-thought-out response.  The class I was poking around to insert my code is SecureDatabaseServerLoginModule, which is, what do you know, a LoginModule!  But it's complicated enough that even the guy who wrote it didn't know that I could add my code here.

The only thing left is whether I have an Http context to pull the IP out of.  Thanks again!